# What does these lines in my Google App Engine log mean?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

[image]

Just checked my log file in GAE, and its thousands of lines of this. Is it something wrong? What does the different lines mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's not coming from us. Do you have any code in your app that looks like

```
logging.info("removing ...
```

Comment: It turned out to be a third party codefile i imported. Thanks!

Comment: In case someone else has the same problem, what were you importing?